# How to call Beginform submit methode before JS submit button click event in mvc?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, onsubmit, html.beginform

I have one form submit method in controller using `BeginForm()` method but in this same method I also have click event on submit button which is in `_Layout.cshtml` page. Currently, first click event is fired then `BeginForm()` method is called.

So, how to first call `BeginForm()` method before submit button click event?

Submit button click event: (`_Layout.cshtml`)

```
$("#SaveData").click(function (b) {
    debugger

    var list = new Array();
    var postData;

    $('input.chkevent').each(function () {
        debugger

        if (this.checked == true) {

            var parent_id = this.parentElement;
            var par2 = parent_id.previousElementSibling;
            var par3 = par2.previousElementSibling;
            var child = par3.childNodes[0];
            var child_val = child.defaultValue;

            var arr_date = this.parentElement.nextElementSibling.childNodes[0].value;
            var dep_date = this.parentElement.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.childNodes[0].value;
            var id = new Array(); ;
            id.push(child_val, arr_date, dep_date);
            list.push(id);
            postData = { values: list};
        }
    });


$.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("FormData", "HomeSurface")',
        //jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true
        //  url: "CheckEvent/PersonEvent?id=" + allVals,
        data: postData,
        type: "POST",
        traditional: true,
        // dataType: "json",
        // traditional: true,
        success: function () {
        }
    });
});
```

Submit_Form (Index.cshtml):

```
 @using (Html.BeginUmbracoForm<HomeSurfaceController>("FormData"))
 {
     <fieldset>
     </fieldset>
 }
```

In controller:

```
 public ActionResult FormData(PERSON_MASTER person, string[] values)
 {

 }
```

Comment: That would be a bit pointless. If the default submit is actioned first, you have posted the data and left the page

Comment: no but I have two kinds of data that must be saved in both during beginform method and also another on click event.

Comment: Once a form is submitted, you have left the page. You need to explain exactly what you trying to achieve and show the code you have tried so far.

Comment: in form, the person details would be saved by beginform method and then after person visited events details would  be saved onSubmit click event.

Comment: Your not making any sense and without seeing code, we can't help

Comment: the code is as above,edited later.